# Can Lookup Field be part of Composite Index?

Tags: lookup, performance, indexing, custom-index

I have an sObject say

> student( ..., student_name text,**favourite_teacher**
>   *lookup*,**marks** *integer*)

By the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_indexes.htm) , lookup fields (favourite_teacher) will be indexed by default.
Is it possible to create a composite index like (favourite_teacher,marks) i.e., one field is lookup and another one is a normal field.

Comment: This might be a question that you'll need to engage Salesforce support for.